# How to draw array of CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

To draw a line from array of CGPoint, i can start with empty beizer path and using -moveToPoint and -addCurveToPoint, i can easily draw a line.

But is there anyway I can directly draw a point on UIView?
Suppose I want to draw a dot with red colour at {5,5}. Suppose my path stroke colour is already red. Does adding these 2 lines meet my purpose or please suggest what can I do to draw a dot at {5,5}

```
[path moveToPoint:{5,5}];
[path addLineToPoint:{5,5}];
```

Comment: you can use loop to draw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it, what we humans call a "dot" is just a really small circle. So to actually draw a dot on the screen, you need to use the `init(ovalIn:)` initializer of `UIBezierPath`.

Here's an example:

```
    let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 2.5, y: 2.5, width: 5, height: 5))
    UIColor.red.setFill()
    dotPath.fill()
```

Note that the x and y values are not `(5,5)`. This is because the x and y here indicate the top left corner of the circle. So you need to do some maths to find that out. You just subtract the radius from the x and y values of the center of the circle.

You can loop through the array and draw each to like this.